# Using Spire.doc, Spire.xls and Spire.Presentation in same project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, spire

Is it possible to use the 3 products in the same project?

Just downloaded the free versions of each and the Spire.PDF.dll version are different and causes error "`System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Spire.Pdf, Version=3.0.10.54040, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=663f351905198cb3' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"`

Spire.doc uses version 3.0.10.54040 and Spire.Presentation uses 3.0.49.58040

I tried using `dependentAssembly`

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Spire.Pdf" publicKeyToken="663f351905198cb3" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.10.54040" newVersion="3.0.49.58040" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

But get an error

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'sprẒ' from assembly 'Spire.Pdf,
Version=3.0.49.58040, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=663f351905198cb3'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alone three libraries can't be used in the same project.  You can download the free  Spire.Office which including libraries of Spire.Doc, Spire XLS, Spire.Presentation, Spire.PDF, Spire.DataExport, Spire.PDFViewer, Spire.DocViewer and so on. Using Spire.Office you can use libraries of Spire.Doc,Spire.Presention and Spire.Xls in same project.

Comment: could you provide a link to download free Spire office? I can only see the individual libraries.

Comment: FreeSpire.Office does not contain anymore PDFViewer library.

Answer (score 0):

Clear out the 'dependentAssembly' section that references the Spire Dlls in your 'app.config' file altogether. That's what worked for me.